# Generate list of duplicates in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I am trying to search a column of descriptions for duplicate items. The wording looks like so:

```
alpha b122

bravo b134

epsilon b122

sigma b134
```

I would like to search for the duplicate `b###` within the column. Is this possible? I don't know the `b###` that I am looking for, my end goal is to find how many times these are repeated.

Comment: What is the output you are searching for here? I am unsure of what exactly your example would result in as a result.

Comment: Your objective isn't clear.  Are you trying to identify any and all duplicates (create a list of, or flag,  values that have duplicates)?  Count how many duplicates there are for each?  Count how many values have duplicates? Have the ability to specify a value and identify whether it has duplicates and/or how many duplicates it has?

Comment: I need to have the ability to identify duplicates without having to input a specific value. I have hundreds of these 'b###' values in each cell and I want to know if any of them are duplicated at all in the column. Each of these identifiers have a prefix as well such as ABCB### or XYZB###. So they are all pretty different.

Comment: So you want a list of each duplicate? So in this case, you would want the output to be b122 and b134?

Comment: @Heather: you need to "address" comments for the person to be aware of your posting.  Your objective still isn't clear.  Can you expand your question to show what the output should be? Highlight duplicated values like theeldest's answer? List the duplicated values like inkyvoyd's comment? Create a table of duplicated values and their duplicate counts? Add a duplicate count next to the first instance of each duplicated value? Are you interested in identifying each record that contains a duplicate or the unique values that are duplicated?

Comment: @fixer1234 I would want my output to be the B# like B122 or b134 and to list the duplicate values would be the best

Comment: @Heather: I think we're almost there.  "...and to list the duplicate values"? I assume you don't mean to just show "b122" twice.  Are you talking about something like after "b122", listing the row numbers that contain "b122"?

Comment: @Heather you can still change the title to something more descriptive I believe. While it might not seem entirely pertinent, it really helps people locate your question as the specific type of excel question it is (you already tagged it as MS excel), and it will help people in the future who are looking for assistance in a similar topic. Also, I've tried to come up with a solution for your question without external add ons or filters, but I am not so sure it is possible to express the results of an array in a single cell.

Comment: @inkyvoyd thanks for your help. I am going to rearrange my data to make this process easier/possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting to highlight the cells that are duplicate items:

1. Select the column that makes up the items you want (I'm going to assume it's column B for this)
2. Create a new conditional formatting rule
3. Enter this formula:

   =if(countif(B:B,B1)>1, True, False)
4. Make sure "Applies to" has:

   =B:B
5. Specify the formatting you want for duplicate items (I would use a fill color)

When you apply that rule all items that have a duplicate in the column will get the formatting you specify.

Comment: I had already tried this and it will only highlight the cells that are exactly the same. Some of the text in the cell is different but the B### is the same, therefore, I am missing alot of duplicates.

Comment: Assuming that your "B###" is in column A, you might want to use the function RIGHT(A:A, 4) to pick the last 4 characters (and hence B###) of the column, place it in a helper column, and filter via helper column.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has data transformation functions that can achieve what you want, in a flexible way that will adapt to new data.

I've built a solution using your examples which you can view or download - its: "Power Query demo - searching for duplicated codes in a list of descriptions.xlsx" in my One Drive:

http://1drv.ms/1H6fLbH

Most of this was built using the point-and-click Power Query UI. The couple of formulas I had to write are described on the "Read Me" sheet.